# Passing in key through `map` function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving a warning about each child in array not having a unique key.

```
const ITEMS = [
    {
        "name": "blah", displayName: "Blah!"
        "name": "blah1", displayName: "Blah1!"
    },
    {
        "name": "blah2", displayName: "Blah2!"
        "name": "blah3", displayName: "Blah3!"
    }
]

item: function(i) {
    return (
        <div key={i.name}>
            <h1>{i.displayName}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            {_.chain(ITEMS).map(this.item, this).value()} # I need to pass in a key here?
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've posted a similar question about a month ago here: ["Each child in an array should have a unique key prop" only on first time render of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469068/each-child-in-an-array-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-only-on-first-time-render). In this case, I need to pass in the key through `map` when it calls the `item()` function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passes the index of the array as the second parameter of the `map` function.

So, you should be able to just add the index to `item`:

```
item: function(currentValue, idx) {
    return (
        <div key={currentValue.name + '-' + idx}>
            <h1>{currentValue.displayName}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

That will ensure that the key is unique and stable.

In your current implementation, `i.name` might not be unique.  In that case, you will get the warning from react.

Also, this object literal might not do what you are intending:

```
{
    "name": "blah", displayName: "Blah!"
    "name": "blah1", displayName: "Blah1!"
}
```

keys like `name` in an object must be unique or you might get undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for that. Didn't know `map` passes the index automatically.