# Passing in a key through a map function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jsx

I'm receiving a warning about each child in an array needing a key. I've encountered this before, and I've solved it in Coffeescript: ["Each child in an array should have a unique key prop" only on first time render of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469068/each-child-in-an-array-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-only-on-first-time-render)

I know that I have to pass in the key through `map`, so that each array that the `map` calls will receive a unique key. In Coffeescript, I could do this:

```
component1 = React.createClass({
    render: () ->
        _.chain(@state.users).map((x) -> <component2 profile={x} key={x.id} />),@).value()
)}

component2 = React.createClass({
render: () ->
    return (
        <div>Test</div>
        <div>Test</div>
    )
})
```

I've attempted to do this in Javascript, and instead of calling a new component, I'm just calling another function inside that same component. I am still receiving the warning:

```
export default class About extends React.Component {
    aboutMe(item) {
        return (
            <div className="col-xs-12">
                <div className="about-body">
                    <p>{item.description}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-xs-9">
                        {_.chain(this.props.about).map(this.aboutMe).value()} # How would I pass in a key in this `map`?
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: So what is `this.aboutMe`, it looks like you're using it as a function, and you probably wanted `.map( x => x.aboutMe )` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

You do the same thing if the `item` has an id (or another property) that can be used as key ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mm38z976/)):

```
aboutMe(item) {
    return (
        <div className="col-xs-12" key={ item.id }>
            <div className="about-body">
                <p>{item.description}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think I'm supposed to pass the key in from the place where the function is called. I've also tried to pass in a key in `aboutMe()` but the warning is still showing up.

Comment: Each JSX element in the array `aboutMe()` creates should have a key. You can do it in `aboutMe()` as well.

Comment: I've added a demo to the answer. Look at the console, and see that there are no warnings about `key`. Then remove `key={ item.id }`, run it, and check the console again. btw - I've used `.map()` instead of lodash's map.

Comment: I've checked the console before adding the `key` and after adding the `key`. The keys are stored in the object and I'm logging them correctly (they are indeed unique).

Comment: I've meant that you should check the demo, I've added to the answer :)

Comment: I did check the demo, and that was what I had in mind originally before posting this question. I even printed out each `item.key` for each component and they all are unique keys. It's strange why it's working on the demo and not on my site.